# How can I check to see if my array has an even permutation?

Tags: c#, permutation

So I've created an array and shuffled it and I want to check if the array has an even permutation. Anyone have an idea as to how i can do that?

```
totalTiles = (column * row) ;
int[] randomNumberArray = new int[totalTiles]; 

for (int p = 0; p < totalTiles; p++)
{
    randomNumberArray[p] = number;
    number++;
}

Shuffle(randomNumberArray);
```

Method to shuffle array

```
static void Shuffle <T>(T[] array)
{
        Random _random = new Random();
        int n = array.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int r = i + _random.Next(n - i);
            T t = array[r];
            array[r] = array[i];
            array[i] = t;
        }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "has an even permutation" ?  Are you wanting to tell if it contains any even numbers?  Or only even numbers?  Use the expression `number % 2 == 0` to detect an even number.

Comment: An even permutation is one that can be performed by doing an even number of swaps of 2 items. So in this case the permutation is even if and only if `n` is even.

Answer (score 0):

Could this possibly help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm generate the permutations then just check if `% 2 == 0` then it's even? Just a guess.

`procedure generate(n : integer, A : array of any):
    if n = 1 then
          output(A)
    else
        for i := 0; i < n - 1; i += 1 do
            generate(n - 1, A)
            if n is even then
                swap(A[i], A[n-1])
            else
                swap(A[0], A[n-1])
            end if
        end for
        generate(n - 1, A)
    end if`

Just quickly taken from the wiki page.